# Android application is not opening from shortcut created on home screen after updating to new version

Tags: android

I have developed an android application whose **first version is already available on Google play.**

Now my problem is, when I installed first version of my app on any android device (Samsung galaxy SII, LG Optimus), it works fine for me.

I have created shortcut of my app on home screen and have moved my app from phone memory to SDCard.

Then I have **install new version** of the same app on my phone and tried to open it from the shortcut that I have created on home screen.

But app is not opening from that **shortcut** and giving me an error message that "**application is not installed on your device"**.

Does anybody have any idea why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you declared one of your activities or permissions twice by accident? You might have declared you launcher activity again somewhere in the Manifest.

Comment: Hey Jani, thanx for the reply. I am using one library project in my application and it has a manifest file in which I have declared my launcher activity again..
But I did the same thing previously in my another application in which case I am not getting this error.

Comment: Why did you declare your launcher activity in another manifest file? Try removing it

Comment: I have tried it by removing launcher activity declarations from manifest file in library project. But problem still persists :(